# Git: Getting a file's path at a given commit hash

Tags: bash, git

Say I have a repository where I have a file, `a.txt`, that at some point got renamed to `b.txt`. Say this happened a long time ago in the history, or maybe a few times, so I'm not quite sure that the file name was at a certain commit.

If I run a `git log` on `b.txt` with the `--follow` flag it looks something like this:

```
$ git log --name-status --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --follow -- 'b.txt'

45c5d11 (HEAD -> master) Edit to 'b.txt'
M       b.txt
cb4ce19 Renaming 'a.txt' to 'b.txt'
R100    a.txt   b.txt
13973ff Edit to 'a.txt'
M       a.txt
9620e34 Adding 'a.txt'
A       a.txt
```

Exactly what I want! But, when I try to `show` the file at a commit when it was named something else, I get this error:

```
$ git show 9620e34:'b.txt'
fatal: path 'b.txt' exists on disk, but not in '9620e34'
```

So, is there either:

- A) A way to get `show` to follow the file renames like `log` does? Or,
- B) A command to return what the path was of a certain file given a commit hash?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is just "no". :-)  Essentially, you must run `git log --follow` and find the name-change yourself, if you can find it at all, and then use the correct name, manually.

The real problem here is that each commit is a complete, but *independent*, snapshot of *all* of your files:

- Commit `9620e34` has one file, `a.txt`.  That's all it has.  It has no `b.txt`.  (Well, it might have other files that are neither `a.txt` nor `b.txt`; I can't tell from the above whether this is the case.)
- Commit `13973ff` has a complete (but different) copy of `a.txt`.
- Commit `cb4ce19` has a complete copy of `b.txt` and no `a.txt` at all.  The copy of `b.txt` in `cb4ce19` matches, 100%, the copy of `a.txt` in `13973ff`—but these are two different file names.
- The last commit, `45c5d11`, has a complete (but different) copy of `b.txt`.

When you use `git log`, what `git log` does is walk through the commits, one commit at a time, starting where you are now (or where you specify) and working backwards.  It can optionally *compare* each commit to its (single) parent,<sup>1</sup> with the parent commit on the left and the child commit on the right.  The comparison of the two snapshots—the diff—produces, as its output, a recipe: *Do these things and you'll change the left-side snapshot's files so that they match the right-side snapshot's files.*  Usually that's pretty close to what someone actually did, or even exactly what they did.  Occasionally, it's not what they did at all, but it produces the same *result*.

With `--name-status`, `git log` prints just the file name and a status letter, rather than the full recipe.<sup>2</sup>  When the recipe includes "rename this file" you get the `R` letter, and a similarity index (percentage): 100 means the files matched, 100% identical, on the left and right sides.  This kind of match is much faster than approximate matches, so when you do the rename without also changing the content of the file, as in this case, it's being nice to Git.  (It might sometimes be nice if Git were nicer back to you.)

Adding the `--follow` option turns on Git's *rename detection* machinery.  It may or may not already be on for various other operations—you can configure `git diff` to control this, for instance, when running `git diff` without specifying `-M` to turn it on manually—but this guarantees that it's on for this particular kind of `git log`.  Finding renames requires that the rename detector run.  The rename detector is computationally expensive (though much less so for 100% matches), so `git log` operations that don't need it generally don't use it at all.

The `--follow` implementation, however, is pretty sleazy: internally, Git chops down each commit to the one file of interest in the child commit, and then compares that file to its counterpart in the parent commit.  If the file isn't *in* the parent, Git invokes the rename detector *for that one file* (rather than for all files as usual) to see if it can find a matching-content-but-different-name file in the parent.<sup>3</sup>  If so, it simply *change the name* that it looks for, while telling you about this one rename.  From this point backwards—remember, `git log` is working backwards—it starts looking for the *old* name instead of the new one.

When you use `git show`, you point it *directly to some commit*.  It does not get there by starting at the last commit and working backwards, the way `git log` does.  It just starts right at the commit you name.  That commit has a parent hash ID (stored in the commit's metadata) and `git show` can therefore `git diff` the parent and child, if you use it as `git show <hash>`; that commit has a snapshot, and `git show` can therefore extract and display one file, if you use it as `git show <hash>:<path>`.  But it hasn't walked backwards from the commit where you are now to that one commit you speciifed, so it has no idea whether the *`path`* you give here might correspond to some other, different, *`path`* in the commit you specified.

Git probably should have some command to trace a file's name: you'd give it an optional starting point, defaulting to `HEAD`, a path name, and a target commit; and it would produce the result of doing the equivalent of `git log --follow` on that name and discovering renames until reaching the target, or produce an error—or perhaps just print the original path—if it never reaches that target commit.  This would be a useful plumbing command.  (It probably should take multiple path names, too, and `git log`'s rename detector should be beefed-up and used to implement this command.)  But it doesn't exist.

---

<sup>1</sup>When `git log` hits a *merge commit*, which—by definition—is one with two or more parents, `git log` usually just doesn't do any comparing at all.  When using `--follow` it changes strategies somewhat, but `--follow` works poorly across merges.

<sup>2</sup>It also cuts out actually *finding* the changes beyond whatever is necessary to come up with the status letter, as finding a change-recipe is slow.

<sup>3</sup>When looking at merges, I'm not sure *what* the rename detector does.  It has all parents available, but the code here is very squirrelly and hard to follow.  In any case there's only a single global variable holding the to-be-followed name, so if the name is different in two different parents, the code literally cannot handle this correctly, for any sensible definition of "correctly".

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough explanation!